# How to create deep table/list and insert/read data from/to it

Tags: java

I wanted to create a table/list in Java, and I wonder what is the best way to handle it.
The table should have a structure like this:

```
Term     propertyList         entitiesList 

a1      p1=1, p2=2, p3=2          T1,T2  
a2      p5=0, p4=5 ,p3=3          T2,T1 
a3      p1=1 ,p4=3, p3=9          T3,T1,T2
...
a10
```

I have a list with exactly 10 terms, and for every term there is a list of properties (**deep with key and value**), and the properties can be either in one or more entities.

I need some help on how to create it, e.g. should I use list, map, collection etc.
How can I add hardcoded values to them as literals in the code, and what is the best way to read data from it, taking into account performance, given that later I will need to use this for every entity and find the related properties that participate in every term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off Create `Term` class.

So you have list of Terms: `List<Term>`

**Term class**

```
public class Term {
   private String mName = "";
   private Map<String, Integer> mPropertyMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
   private List<String> mEntitiesList = new ArrayList<String>();

   public Term(String name) {
       mName = name;
   }

   public void generate(Map<String, Integer> propertyMap,   List<String> entitiesList) {
    mPropertyMap = propertyMap;
    mEntitiesList = entitiesList;
   }

  public Map<String, Integer> getPropertyMap() {
    return mPropertyMap;
}

public void setPropertyMap(Map<String, Integer> propertyMap) {
    this.mPropertyMap = propertyMap;
}

public List<String> getEntitiesList() {
    return mEntitiesList;
}

public void setEntitiesList(List<String> entitiesList) {
    this.mEntitiesList = entitiesList;
}

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setmName(String name) {
    this.mName = name;
}

}
```

**Main Class**

```
 public class MyClass {

private List<Term> mTermList = null;

private void init() {
    mTermList = new ArrayList<Term>();
}


private void addSomeTerm() {
     Map<String, Integer> propertyMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

     propertyMap.put("p1", 1);
     propertyMap.put("p2", 2);
     propertyMap.put("p3", 3);

     List<String> entitiesList = new ArrayList<String>();
     entitiesList.add("T1");
     entitiesList.add("T2");


     Term term = new Term("a1");
     term.generate(propertyMap, entitiesList);

     mTermList.add(term);
}

private String printTerms() {

    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();

    for(Term currTerm : mTermList){

        buff.append(currTerm.getName()).append("     ");

        Map<String, Integer> propertyMap = currTerm.getPropertyMap();


        Set<String> sets = propertyMap.keySet();

        Iterator<String> itr = sets.iterator();

        String key = null;
        Integer value = null;

        while(itr.hasNext()){

            key = itr.next();               
            value = propertyMap.get(key);

            buff.append(key + "=" + value).append(",");
        }

        buff.setLength(buff.length()-1); // remove last ','

        buff.append("     ");

        List<String> entitiesList = currTerm.getEntitiesList();

        for(String str : entitiesList){
            buff.append(str).append(",");
        }

        buff.setLength(buff.length()-1); // remove last ','         

    }

    return buff.toString();
}


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyClass m = new MyClass();
    m.init();

    m.addSomeTerm();

    System.out.println(m.printTerms());
}
```

}

Output:

```
 a1     p1=1,p2=2,p3=3     T1,T2
```

Comment: Can you please provide some little example how can I add for it data to it like I provide in the example. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could have the following structure:

```
class Term {
    String id;
    Map<String, String> properties;
    List<Entity> entities; // (or Set<Entity> if no duplicates are allowed)
}
```

But it's not very clear what you mean by "deep" and by "the properties can be either in one or more entities".

Comment: I mean that the properties can have key which is the name of the property and value.. ,why you  create it with class? and how can I add to it data like I have in the table. thanks!!!

Comment: Java is an object oriented language. You can't create data structures other than classes. It looks like you need to learn the basics. Google for "Oracle Java tutorial".